# Can I store the videos in my own server when using the YouTube API?

Tags: youtube

We are proposing to use the YouTube API for a community video portal. When using the Upload API and the Player API ... I have the following queries ...

1. Can I store all the videos in my own Server, instead of storing on YouTube?
2. Will the uploaded videos on my site also appear on youtube.com automatically? Can I restrict the display of our videos on the YouTube site, as these come through a Pay wall?
3. Are there any restrictions to the number of videos being uploaded using the API?

Rregards